# How do you manage per env config file using ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

I'm using ansible to install Apache, currently I have multiple `httpd.conf` files(test/dev/staging/production) in ansible repository, most of the content is same excepts some environment specific settings.

Is it possible to use one `httpd.conf` template file, and modify the file when send the `httpd.conf` to remote server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can. With jinja2 and group_vars.

So what you do in your templates/ folder create a file like such:

```
templates/http.conf.j2
```

Say you have something like this in there:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName {{ subdomain }}.{{ domain }}
    ServerAlias www.{{ subdomain }}.{{ domain }}
</VirtualHost>
```

Your layout should look like this:

```
├── group_vars
│   ├── all
│   │   └── config
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── config
│   └── test
│       └── config
├── inventory
│   ├── dev
│   │   └── hosts
│   └── test
│       └── hosts
├── site.yml
└── templates
    └── http.conf.j2
```

In `group_vars/all` you would have `domain: "example.com"`

In `group_vars/dev` you would have `subdomain: dev`

In `group_vars/test` you would have `subdomain: test`

In your task, you'd have your ansible template command i.e.

```
- hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: Copy http conf
        template:
        dest: /etc/apache2/http.conf
        src: templates/http.conf.j2
        owner: root
        group: root
```

And run your playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory/test site.yml
```

The file should end up on the host looking like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.example.com
    ServerAlias www.test.example.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do you have a complete project test to share?